# Disable all messages when open DWG

Tags: delphi, ole, autocad

I'm developing application for converting DWG to PDF. Developing on Delphi using AutoCAD OLE. The best solution I found it's using Publish command. It work OK, but the problem is when I open DWG file some messages can appear. For a example, it can be missing SHX files message, or remember file was created in an earlier version, about ObjectARX and so on. Of course these messages appear when manually opening these DWG in AutoCAD.
But, for a example, when using Excel via OLE it has silent mode, so no messages will appear.
Is any similar in AutoCAD?
There is some system variables like FILEDIA or EXPERT (I use it) but it available only in document, when it opened already, not for application.

Here is a part of my code, where I open DWG:

```
...
CoInitializeEx(nil, 0);
AutoCAD := GetActiveOleObject('AutoCAD.Application');//connect to running AutoCAD
if not VarIsNull(AutoCAD) then
begin
  cadDocument := AutoCAD.Documents.Open(InputFilename, True);//here's problem line code
  ...
end;
...
```

Comment: This is much an Autocad problem than a Delphi issue. What does Autocad OLE documentation say? Where are those messages supposed to go? Once you know that, a Delphi solution can probably be found.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it's about AutoCAD. The problem that the most settings only for document (system variables and so on), not the AutoCAD application. But we need do something before open doc. The question what is.

Comment: What does Autocad automation doc say? Is that doc publicly available? If yes, where?

Comment: Yes, it's public. Here about open method - http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/PLK/?guid=GUID-9ED7A548-7978-4BFD-8462-E2FA747E8880

Comment: Reading the docs, I understand the when using VBA the errors are trapped by On Error VBA construct. This is probably an event at the ActivX level.